# ZF 2 Zend\Form\Element\Date not Creating Calendar in the view

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In my Form i am using something like this

```
  $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'date1',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Date',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Date:',
        )
    ));
```

And in my view i am using this

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('date1'));
```

But it is not creating any calendar.

**Edit**: Got this issue in Fire Fox, got some kind of calendar in Chrome i dont know why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is an HTML5 feature that is currently only supported in Chrome and Opera out of the box.
When Can I Use: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Just to add to this answer, all that `Element\Date` does is to render out `<input type="date" />` and as ChandlerTi said, the features vary going by browser. If you need x-browser support, unfortunately you're still stuck with JavaScript

Comment: so at the moment my best hopes are Jquery?